# LXC: Cgroups, hardware passthrough, explain in english please?

Tags: debian, hardware, lxc, proxmox

I've got sort of a niche use case (not "production", it's a lab environment for a classroom) where I am using LXC containers on a Proxmox VE machine to run GNS3 Server and KVM virtualization.

To make a long story short, I need to run KVM *inside* an LXC container, which means I have to pass through the host machine's CPU virtualization features to the container. I already have this working based on some tutorials I read, but I don't understand *why* it works. I have no idea what these config file lines actually do, I just blindly copy-pasted.

Here is my container config (from `/etc/pve/lxc/102.conf`):

```
arch: amd64
cores: 2
hostname: ubuntu-gns3vm2-clone
memory: 4096
net0: name=eth0,bridge=vmbr0,hwaddr=86:4B:53:B7:66:0A,ip=dhcp,type=veth
ostype: ubuntu
rootfs: local-lvm:base-102-disk-0,size=16G
swap: 2048
template: 1

# LINES IN QUESTION
# This line seems to pass through the host CPU's virtualization features
lxc.cgroup.devices.allow: c 10:232 rwm

# These lines were needed for virtual machine networking to behave, I don't really understand them either
lxc.cgroup.devices.allow: c 10:200 rwm
lxc.mount.entry: /dev/net/tun dev/net/tun none bind,create=file
```

Can someone decipher these for me? Where do the `10:232` and `10:200` numbers come from? What is a cgroup? What does `/dev/net/tun` actually do?

Like I said, nothing is misbehaving, it's all working fine, I just don't want to deploy something I don't fully understand. Feel free to ELI5.

Answer (score 4):

As far as I known, there's no hardware passthrough in containers: USB devices, PCI devices, KVM, etc. are always available as long as permissions to use them are not removed by various isolation mechanisms used in containers, or perhaps unless their driver/layer include namespace awareness allowing them to change behaviour depending on namespace. Here's a non exhaustive list of such isolation mechanisms:

- capabilities . Eg in `/usr/share/lxc/config/common.conf`:

  > ```
  > # Drop some harmful capabilities
  > lxc.cap.drop = mac_admin mac_override sys_time sys_module sys_rawio
  > ```
- cgroups. Eg in `/usr/share/lxc/config/common.conf`:

  > ```
  > # CGroup whitelist
  > lxc.cgroup.devices.deny = a
  > ## Allow any mknod (but not reading/writing the node)
  > lxc.cgroup.devices.allow = c *:* m
  > lxc.cgroup.devices.allow = b *:* m
  > ## Allow specific devices
  > ### /dev/null
  > lxc.cgroup.devices.allow = c 1:3 rwm
  > ```
  >
  > [...]
- seccomp. Eg in `/usr/share/lxc/config/common.seccomp`:

  > ```
  > kexec_load errno 1
  > open_by_handle_at errno 1
  > init_module errno 1
  > finit_module errno 1
  > delete_module errno 1
  > ```

These are the main machanisms, there are others (eg: `pivot_root`/`mount` when the container is started, or mounting fake entries over some portions of `/proc/` or `/sys/` to prevent access).

Mimic-ing a passthrough can be done in multiple ways depending on the kind of ressource. Eg: most network *interfaces* (not their underlying hardware (or virtual...) network device) have direct [support for namespaces](https://manpages.debian.org/manpages/network_namespaces.7) and can be moved around namespaces without trouble. It's a base concept for containers. It's not the same as passing through the whole *device* like is done with a VM.

Now if it's an USB serial device exposing for example `/dev/ttyUSB0`, there's no such namespace support. This requires copying (using `mknod`) the relevant `/dev/` entry, which usually has a dynamic device node value which won't help making a simple configuration, and adding various permissions that were removed by default (see cgroups above) to restore access to this device. Again, there was no device passthrough involved.

---

So, for your KVM case. Access was first removed (that's the default 
`lxc.cgroup.devices.deny = a`), and you add it back (`lxc.cgroup.devices.allow: c 10:232 rwm`). `c 10:232` describes a device node of type character with [char major 10](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/Documentation/admin-guide/devices.txt?h=v4.19#n250) and [minor 232](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/Documentation/admin-guide/devices.txt?h=v4.19#n368): `232 = /dev/kvm     Kernel-based virtual machine (hardware virtualization extensions)`, that's the reserved tuple for KVM.

QEMU/KVM is creating and using [`TUN/TAP` devices](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/networking/tuntap.txt) (instead of `veth` interfaces used with containers) to have network connectivity, so permission to use them by QEMU/KVM should be added back, that's what are the lines related to tun below (the [Linux documented entry for `c 10:200`](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/Documentation/admin-guide/devices.txt?h=v4.19#n336) is `200 = /dev/net/tun   TAP/TUN network device`). Also, as `mount` is forbidden inside the container, LXC pre-mount the original `/dev/net` for it to be able to use the original `/dev/net/tun`. I think an other method would have been, in the container, to create the directory `/dev/net` and  create the same node (`c 10:200`) `/dev/net/tun`.

If you have to add more devices, you can first do some tests with `lxc-attach -e` which bypasses all limitations (eg: access to a device, using `mount` or `rmmod` all work) and then see what permissions should be added back in the configuration.